# How can I fix these errors that only happens in Visual C++ but not in DevC++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <windows.h>     

typedef short _stdcall (*PtrInp)(short EndPorta);
typedef void _stdcall (*PtrOut)(short EndPorta, short datum);
HINSTANCE hLib;
PtrInp inportB;
PtrOut outportB;

int main()
{
/*Inpout32*/
   //Carrega a DLL na memória.
   hLib = LoadLibrary("inpout32.dll");
   if(hLib == NULL)
   {
       printf("Error.");
      getch();
   }
else {

   inportB = (PtrInp) GetProcAddress(hLib, "Inp32");
   if(inportB == NULL)
   {
      printf("\nError2");
   }
   //Obtém o endereço da função Out32 contida na DLL.
   outportB = (PtrOut) GetProcAddress(hLib, "Out32");
   if(outportB == NULL)
   {

      printf("Error3");

   }
}
```

When I compile using DevC++, the code works just fine, but when I try to compile it in Visual C++ it gives a bunch of errors, how can I fix them?

The following errors is shown in the output:

```
1><PATH>(12) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
1><PATH>(13) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
1><PATH>(15) : error C2065: 'PtrInp' : undeclared identifier
1><PATH>(15) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'inportB'
1><PATH>(15) : error C2065: 'inportB' : undeclared identifier
1><PATH>(16) : error C2065: 'PtrOut' : undeclared identifier
1><PATH>(16) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'outportB'
1><PATH>(16) : error C2065: 'outportB' : undeclared identifier
1><PATH>(30) : error C2065: 'inportB' : undeclared identifier
1><PATH>(30) : error C2065: 'PtrInp' : undeclared identifier
1><PATH>(30) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetProcAddress'
1><PATH>(31) : error C2065: 'inportB' : undeclared identifier
1><PATH>(36) : error C2065: 'outportB' : undeclared identifier
1><PATH>(36) : error C2065: 'PtrOut' : undeclared identifier
1><PATH>(36) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetProcAddress'
1><PATH>(37) : error C2065: 'outportB' : undeclared identifier
1><PATH>(53) : error C3861: 'outportB': identifier not found
1><PATH>(56) : error C3861: 'outportB': identifier not found
1><PATH>(59) : error C3861: 'outportB': identifier not found
1><PATH>(62) : error C3861: 'outportB': identifier not found
1><PATH>(65) : error C3861: 'outportB': identifier not found
1><PATH>(68) : error C3861: 'outportB': identifier not found
1><PATH>(71) : error C3861: 'outportB': identifier not found
1><PATH>(74) : error C3861: 'outportB': identifier not found
1><PATH>(80) : error C3861: 'outportB': identifier not found
```

Comment: What's the toolchain you're actually using with [tag:dev-c++]?

Comment: I'm not really sure what a toolchain it is, but I'm compiling on Windows XP SP3, DevC++ uses Mingw compiler. Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under MSVC the calling convention should be placed within the parenthesis

```
typedef short (__stdcall *PtrInp)(short EndPorta);
typedef void (__stdcall *PtrOut)(short EndPorta, short datum);
```

Please also make sure you use *MBCS* (Mutli Byte Charecter Set) within your project settings

Answer (score 1):

It has to be `__stdcall`, i.e. a double-underscore. In addition to this, the classifier `__stdcall` should be applied to the function itself, not to the return value:

```
typedef short (__stdcall *PtrInp)(short EndPorta);
typedef void (__stdcall *PtrOut)(short EndPorta, short datum);
```

See more examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx